# MySQL user loses privileges

Tags: mysql

I have really weird problem that I can't wrap my mind around. I'm using Debian Jessie for our servers. I've added testing repos and upgraded mysql version from 5.5 to 5.7.2 then setup private network between 2 servers:

Server A - 192.168.0.1 as database server

Server B - 192.168.0.2 as application server

I've created user and gave him all required privileges (i've tested multiple hosts and multiple variations of global and database privileges). Everything is working fine but randomly after couple days the user starts getting "Access denied" and can not log in to the database. Communication between servers works just fine, servers can ping each other and connection to mysql is not blocked as its sending Access Denied as response. I've flushed privileges many times and the user has no limits by default.

I've turned off firewall and checked system logs and I don't see anything even remotely related to my problem. I've tried all steps suggested by mysql docs where they suggest possible solutions to "Access Denied". I've tried with different app/database. I've tried many different users with both wildcard and classic hosts definitions, with different permissions and after couple days my application server is still getting "Access denied". If I log in locally on the database server and perform "Show grants" and "Show databases" everything seems fine - user has correct host and privileges yet can not log in remotely.

Application stack used for our apps is PHP with Symfony2/3. Is there anything I can do about it? Is there any software that could help me debug?

Comment: Try to access it with mysql workbench. You sure you didn't change anything? Have you tried changing the user to root to see if it's indeed the issue with the user account? How are you connecting to the database?

Comment: Your question is missing many things.  For example, what is the specific GRANT you use?  The implication is that you are doing something to remedy the issue.  Are you recreating the user?  Did you investigate the tables in the data dictionary? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant-tables.html

Comment: I was not sure first time it happened now I'm sure it behaves for root in same way. @gview I've been testing many approaches, from classic console create->grant GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'testuser'@'192.168.0.%/255.255.255.0'; in many variations like 'testuser'@'192.168.0.1' or for specific database. I've perfomed tests with single accounts (to remove the possibility that mysql uses account with wrong hostname). I've checked privileges tables manually and there was nothing suspcious.

Comment: I've tried from phpmyadmin too, I'm even flushing privileges, restarting services and then the server itself after user changes and it works but just for couple days.

Comment: @abr I was not perfoming any changes to mysql users, everything was fine for couple days then the user started getting Access Denied. Locally user has all required privileges yet can not connect remotely. Adding new users after this gives access denied too for some time then it starts working (it may be couple hours). Mysql Workbench can connect just fine as long as the problem is not occuring. At the moment its working I'm just trying to find out the source as I can't really let it happen again. As for the connection we are using symfony with doctrine and pdo_mysql driver.